# Adding onnxruntime Library to a .Net Core Docker Container for Linux

Tags: docker, .net-core, onnxruntime

I am trying to deploy a game server on a .NET 5.0 Docker container for Linux deployment. My current Dockerfile looks like this, and it has been working fine so far. My code is packaged into a dll that is in the Darkrift_Server_Local/Plugins folder. Darkrift.Server.Console.dll is a third-party networking wrapper that loads the plugin and runs my logic:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
COPY DarkRift_Server_Local/ App/
EXPOSE 4296/udp
EXPOSE 4296/tcp
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./Lib/DarkRift.Server.Console.dll"]
```

Now I want to add a pre-trained ONNX model to my server for AI opponents to use. I have added the Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime Nuget package to my project, and my code works when I run it on my Windows 10 (using a powershell to execute Darkrift.Server.Console.dll).

However, I am not able to make this work in the Docker container, because it is unable to locate the onnxruntime.dll file. The specific error is below:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.NativeMethods' threw an exception.
>
> ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'onnxruntime' or one of its dependencies.

I've tried copying the onnxruntime.dll file, generated during the build, to various locations in the Darkrift_Server_Local folder, but it has not been working. I'm rather new to Docker and have gotten back to .NET after several years, so having a little trouble figuring out how this is supposed to work. Would appreciate any direction on this.

EDIT: In response to the comment. I'm building the project using VS2019 with Release/Any CPU. The package inclusion code is as follows:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="com.playfab.csharpgsdk" Version="0.10.200325" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have also tried using dotnet publish -c Release and copying over the runtimes folder that is created in the publish folder to various locations in my Darkrift_Server_Local folder - should have mentioned that.

Comment: How are you building the application before your docker build?

Comment: Hi - have added some details to the post. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are compiling on Windows, but using Linux container, you have to make sure that you are [publishing for the correct runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).

First, publish with `dotnet publish -r linux-x64`. You may want to specific `-o <path>` to make it easier to find.

You can then copy those inside your image with your `Dockerfile`.

Alternatively, you could build/publish in your `Dockerfile` itself to avoid platform issues like this.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it seems there was a separate onnxruntime library for Linux that I needed to include instead of the Windows DLL. I also tried building within a Docker image and that works as well. Appreciate the guidance...